# Convert XYZ file with WGS84 Ellipsoid elevations to EGM96 Geoid elevations

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, datum, ellipsoid, geoid

I have multiple files in XYZ format in UTM horizontal + WGS84 ellipsoid vertical that I need to convert to UTM horizontal EGM96 geoid elevations. There are about 250'000 points in a an area that is 3km on 25km approximately.
The points mostly bathymetry points located 5cm to 1m from each other so sampling a raster DEM will not work.

Is there a way do that using gdal, python script, Qgis or Arcgis ?

---

What I found so far:

- The NGA's page where one can get EGM96 elevations from lat/long coordinates but that only works one point at a time.
- EPSG:10084 seems to provide transformation from WGS84 to EGM96 but I couldn't find how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The United States National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration distributes a freeware package called [vDatum](https://vdatum.noaa.gov/) for doing vertical datum transformations.  vDatum is a Java executable file so there are some installation steps and dependent software (like the appropriate version of Java).

vDatum will accept a text file as input.

Here is a link to the [User Guide](https://vdatum.noaa.gov/docs/userguide.html).

Her is a link to th [Datum tutorial](https://vdatum.noaa.gov/docs/userguide.html).

Sin you asked about GDAL or Python you might be intrested in [Using vDatum at the command line](https://vdatum.noaa.gov/docs/userguide_cmd.html).